# Power BI - Hide Row in Subtotal

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to hide a specific row in a Matrix Table, the row I need to remove is a category row, with specific sub categories associated with it in the data model.

As example 1 below points out:  I need to keep rows A,B,C but hide the Exclude header row.
I have tried filters, but this hides the entire header row, and sub categories.

I think using DAX would be the best way, in my table I have a DAX measure created that returns values based on a SWITCH function, as described below in example 2. What DAX code do I need to add to this SWITCH statement that would hide the "Exclude" row, from the table?

```
**
 - Example 1.
**

Exclude  .................................
  A      .................................   
  B      .................................
  C      .................................

 - **Example 2:**

RETURN
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    CurrentCategory IN { "Active Sample", "Non Active Sample", "Exclude" }
            && NOT ( ISINSCOPE ( HeaderAssignment2[Disp_Code_Description] ) ), BLANK (),
    NOT ( ISBLANK ( CurrentVal ) ), CurrentVal,
    NOT ( ISBLANK ( AnyVal ) ), 0
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85wkx.png)

Comment: So you're trying to blank out the subtotal row values?

Comment: Hi Alexis, I am trying to hide the "Exclude" row, per example 1, and keep the other rows as specified in example 1 as as "A","B","C".

Comment: So you want to hide the row entirely rather than just blanking the values? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Can you show a snapshot of your Metrix (with dummy data) marking the row you wants to exclude?

Comment: Hi, I added a link to the image of the matrix in this post, the red line shows the row I need to hide.  The row called "Exclude" is a category header for the subcategories below it, I need to just hide the Exclude row, and keep all the other ones.

Comment: You can filter that row from filters pane